# How to extract value (hour / minute) from a data field in MS Access?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a column with data fields in MS-Access and I need to generate two new different columns with the value of the hour and of the minute.

```
Data column: 24/03/2015 20:33
```

I need a column with hour value (20) and a column with minutes value (33)

I think I have to set an update query, but I am not able to set up the formulas.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. When you say "extract", do you mean export the data to Excel? Or are you trying to add, change or delete the values in the table (that is what an update query will do)? If all you want to do is read the data from the table, use a lookup query. What have you attempted and what problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: You should give examples of the data you're using. We don't know what format the data is, or maybe it's unix time? Please put some effort in your question!

Comment: Data column 24/03/2015 20:33, I need a column with hout value (20) and a column with minutes value (33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Access already have functions called Hour and Minute to retrieve the value for you already. It is a matter of updating that value into the fields via your update query.

[Hour](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/hour.php)

```
Hour (#10:42:58 PM#) 
Result: 22
```

[Minute](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/minute.php)

```
Minute (#10:42:58 PM#)
Result: 42
```